# grep doesn't recognize [A-Z]+

Tags: regex, grep

```
$ grep 'tableName="' db.changelog.xml
    <createTable tableName="MY_TABLE" schemaName="public">

$ grep 'tableName="[A-Z_]+"' db.changelog.xml
```

The second grep doesn't return anything. Why is that?

This is the LANG that is configured by default.

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.24
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Basic Regular Expression (BRE) mode, `+` is interpreted as a literal character.

You have several options:

- use `grep -E` to enable Extended Regular Expression support
- use `\{1,\}` to mean *one or more* in BRE mode (POSIX-compliant, should work on any grep)
- use `\+`, which is understood by GNU grep to mean *one or more* in BRE mode

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
grep 'tableName="[A-Z_]\+"' db.changelog.xml
```

i.e. add an `\` before the `+`. If you find this counter-intuitive, use can use extended regular expressions or perl style regular expressions with the flags `-E` and `-P` respectively, e.g.

```
grep -P 'tableName="[A-Z_]+"' db.changelog.xml
```